# Filtering issues (no change in contents) in datatable primefaces 3.5, sorting works

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, filtering

Primefaces 3.5 doesn't seem to filter data at all from the datatable, oddly enough it somehow reorders them as I type, so, there must be some AJAX calls firing, but obviously not the right ones.

```
<h:panelGroup id="table-wrapper-component">
            <prime:dataTable
                rendered="#{artifactSelectionBackingBean.visibleComps}"
                value="#{artifactSelectionBackingBean.components}"
                var="tagInfoObject" emptyMessage="No tags found with given criteria"
                filteredValue="#{artifactSelectionBackingBean.filteredComponents}">

                <prime:ajax event="filter" global="false" />

                <prime:column sortBy="#{tagInfoObject.tagId}"
                    headerText="Identifier" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy = "#{tagInfoObject.tagId}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{tagInfoObject.tagId}" />
                </prime:column>

                <prime:column sortBy="#{tagInfoObject.type.tagTypeId}"
                    headerText="Tag Identifier" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy ="#{tagInfoObject.type.tagTypeId}"> 
                    <h:outputText value="#{tagInfoObject.type.tagTypeId}" />
                </prime:column>

                <prime:column sortBy="#{tagInfoObject.title}" headerText="Title" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{tagInfoObject.title}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{tagInfoObject.title}" />
                </prime:column>

                <prime:column filterBy="#{tagInfoObject.description}"
                    filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{tagInfoObject.description}"
                    styleClass="wrap" headerText="Component Description">
                    <h:outputText value="#{tagInfoObject.description}" />
                </prime:column>

            </prime:dataTable>
        </h:panelGroup>
```

Any help is appreciated! All the Beans and method calls exist and return the appropriate data, just that the filtering doesn't seem to work at all.

Also, note that sorting functions properly only filtering does not!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that you always need to wrap any filtering/sorting attributes in a data table with an `h:form` tag. This is not explicitly specified in the documentation of PrimeFaces, however, it is in the showcase [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf). I wrapped the whole thing in form tags.

So, don't forget to wrap your data tables in a form if you want any type of interaction provided by primefaces.

Answer (score 0):

Your managed Bean Code will do a lot of good 
Post your managed bean code.

May be you have not set the value for **artifactSelectionBackingBean.filteredComponents** in the managed bean

Comment: No, that was not the problem the issue was that the I forgot to wrap the panel in a <h:form> tag. Apparently, that was the issue and both sorting and filtering work now.